# Return function data into an Array

Tags: arrays, swift, macos, function

I have found away to search and return data of current USB's plugged into the system.

I can print this by using `print(usbDelegate())` Return:

device added: Cruzer Fit
device added: USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter
device added: USB2.0 Hub
device added: USB3.0 Hub

What I would like to do is return these values into an array? Like this:

```
var usbDevices = [Cruzer Fit, USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter, USB2.0 Hub, USB3.0 Hub]
```

Here is the code that I used to scan for USB's:

```
import Cocoa
import IOKit
import IOKit.usb
import IOKit.usb.IOUSBLib

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func usbSelect(_ sender: Any) {

        print(usbDelegate())

    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}

public protocol USBWatcherDelegate: class {
    /// Called on the main thread when a device is connected.
    func deviceAdded(_ device: io_object_t)

    /// Called on the main thread when a device is disconnected.
   func deviceRemoved(_ device: io_object_t)
}

/// An object which observes USB devices added and removed from the system.
/// Abstracts away most of the ugliness of IOKit APIs.
public class USBWatcher {
    private weak var delegate: USBWatcherDelegate?
    private let notificationPort = IONotificationPortCreate(kIOMasterPortDefault)
    private var addedIterator: io_iterator_t = 0
    private var removedIterator: io_iterator_t = 0



public init(delegate: USBWatcherDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate

        func handleNotification(instance: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, _ iterator: io_iterator_t) {
            let watcher = Unmanaged<USBWatcher>.fromOpaque(instance!).takeUnretainedValue()
            let handler: ((io_iterator_t) -> Void)?
            switch iterator {
            case watcher.addedIterator: handler = watcher.delegate?.deviceAdded
            case watcher.removedIterator: handler = watcher.delegate?.deviceRemoved
            default: assertionFailure("received unexpected IOIterator"); return
            }
            while case let device = IOIteratorNext(iterator), device != IO_OBJECT_NULL {
                handler?(device)
                IOObjectRelease(device)
            }
        }

        let query = IOServiceMatching(kIOUSBDeviceClassName)
        let opaqueSelf = Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()

        // Watch for connected devices.
        IOServiceAddMatchingNotification(
            notificationPort, kIOMatchedNotification, query,
            handleNotification, opaqueSelf, &addedIterator)

        handleNotification(instance: opaqueSelf, addedIterator)

        // Watch for disconnected devices.
        IOServiceAddMatchingNotification(
            notificationPort, kIOTerminatedNotification, query,
            handleNotification, opaqueSelf, &removedIterator)

        handleNotification(instance: opaqueSelf, removedIterator)

        // Add the notification to the main run loop to receive future updates.
        CFRunLoopAddSource(
            CFRunLoopGetMain(),
            IONotificationPortGetRunLoopSource(notificationPort).takeUnretainedValue(),
            .commonModes)
    }

    deinit {
        IOObjectRelease(addedIterator)
        IOObjectRelease(removedIterator)
        IONotificationPortDestroy(notificationPort)
    }
}

extension io_object_t {
    /// - Returns: The device's name.
    func name() -> String? {
        let buf = UnsafeMutablePointer<io_name_t>.allocate(capacity: 1)
        defer { buf.deallocate() }
        return buf.withMemoryRebound(to: CChar.self, capacity: MemoryLayout<io_name_t>.size) {
            if IORegistryEntryGetName(self, $0) == KERN_SUCCESS {
                return String(cString: $0)
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}

class usbDelegate: USBWatcherDelegate {
    private var usbWatcher: USBWatcher!
    init() {
        usbWatcher = USBWatcher(delegate: self)
    }

    func deviceAdded(_ device: io_object_t) {

        print("device added: \(device.name() ?? "<unknown>")")
    }

    func deviceRemoved(_ device: io_object_t) {
        print("device removed: \(device.name() ?? "<unknown>")")
    }
}

var example = usbDelegate()
```

I have been looking for a while now and haven't seen anything to achieve this. Help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Where do you want to use this array?

Answer (score 0):

You can return Array from this function

```
func deviceAdded(_ device: io_object_t)-> [String] {


        print("device added: \(device.name() ?? "<unknown>")")

        return [device.name()]
    }
```